# Could you actually see the event horizon of a Black Hole?

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, observers, event-horizon, gravitational-lensing

For years I thought to myself that surely you'd be able to see the event horizon of a Black Hole when looking at it against the surrounding light. I thought that it would be similar to this: 
[image]

Where you can see the surrounding light, and the Black Hole would be "highly" noticeable due to being a strange Black dot that is completely out of place.

This is what I thought until a friend mentioned that surely it would actually be completely invisible as none of that surrounding light would actually reach my eyes due to being pulled in by the black hole. It makes a lot of sense but I'm just slightly confused now, Is this true? would a Black Hole be completely invisible?

Comment: Yes, it's a black circle. Due to the gravitational lensing (light bending), the circle would appear 2.5 times larger than it actually is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#/media/File%3ABlackHole_Lensing.gif